# Time in mysql and php on two different servers

Tags: mysql, database, linux

I have my php site on a server and database on another, I want to check the time on the other server holding the database, this way i can synchronize both servers at the same time to avoid time gaps.

For my current server i simply do time(). But how i can get time for mysql database?

Comment: For simplicity's sake, you should store all times in `UTC` and only modify timezones on display.

Comment: would you be able to clarify your requirement? What kind of precision are you after, and why do you need to eliminate time gaps in the first place? A database request takes time, and by the time you're getting your response, the result is already slightly outdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an operational problem which needs to be solved by your operations engineers (for example, using NTP). Operations should also monitor clock sync.

It is reasonable to develop your application assuming that the clocks will stay (mostly) in sync.

I normally like to assume that

- Clocks will be synchronised to within a few seconds
- Clocks never run backwards by more than a few seconds

I guess if you assume those, you're going to be alright.

However you can do

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of NOW() and TIME() to fetch the time from the database server. Have a look at the supported [date and time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) functions that MySQL supports.

```
SELECT TIME(NOW());
```

The above should work fine for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to synchronize between your servers, in this case it will be better to use [NTP server](http://www.akadia.com/services/ntp_synchronize.html).